# Optimizing a MySql query: Query only having 'using where' in explain extra

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with following schema:

```
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----+---------+-----------+
|        Field         |     Type     |         Null | Key | Default |     Extra |
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----+---------+-----------+
| request_id           | bigint(20)   | NO           | PRI |         |           |
| marketplace_id       | int(11)      | NO           | PRI |         |           |
| feed_attribute_name  | varchar(256) | NO           | PRI |         |           |
| full_update_count    | int(11)      | NO           |     |         |           |
| partial_update_count | int(11)      | NO           |     |         |           |
| ptd                  | varchar(256) | NO           | PRI |         |           |
| processed_date       | datetime     | NO           | PRI |         |           |
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----+---------+-----------+
```

and I am querying it like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(full_update_count) as total FROM 
x.attribute_usage_information WHERE marketplace_id=6 
AND ptd='Y' AND processed_date>2013-12-31 AND 
feed_attribute_name='abc'
```

The query plan is:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len    ref     rows         Extra
1   SIMPLE      X       ALL                                            1913668816   Using where
```

I am new to query optimization so my inferences can be wrong.
I am surprised that it is not using index which can be a reason for its slow execultion(around an hour). The table size is of order of `10^10`. Can this query be rewritten so that it uses index because where clause is part a subset of the primary key set for the table?

EDIT: SHOW INDEX result

```
+---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+------
|Table                      | Non_unique |  Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment
|attribute_usage_information |   0        |   PRIMARY  | 1            | request_id     | A  2901956             BTREE   
|attribute_usage_information |   0        |   PRIMARY  | 2            | marketplace_id | A  2901956             BTREE   
|attribute_usage_information |   0        |   PRIMARY  | 3            |                | feed_attribute_name    A   273613033               BTREE   
|attribute_usage_information |   0        |   PRIMARY  | 4            | ptd            | A  1915291236              BTREE   
|attribute_usage_information |   0        |   PRIMARY  | 5            | processed_date | A  1915291236              BTREE
```

EDIT 2: SHOW GRANT RESULT

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'data_usage_rw'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD *** WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: I assume `request_id` is the leading edge(first column) of your PK and your query doesn't refer it.

Comment: @OracleUser How can we find if it is a leading edge or not?

Comment: [SHOW INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-index.html) should help you! Thats why people suggest for the `secondary` index or `covering` index, when the primary key may not be usable for these conditions.

Comment: @OracleUser Yes. please see the edit for more details.

Comment: Since first column has to be skipped.. going for `INDEX SKIP` scan over your Priamry Key index is costly for such a huge table. So optimiser preferred the `FULL TABLE` scan instead. This is a very common situation, where dev go for either partitioning or create a secondary index. Which surely needs DBA involvement.!

Comment: @OracleUser I checked and I do have `alter grant` on this database. Can I create secondry index for this table without DBA involvement?

Comment: better to consult them first, as it consumes additional space in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Cover your `WHERE` conditions with a composite `index(marketplace_id,ptd,processed_date,feed_attribute_name)`

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD INDEX (marketplace_id,ptd,processed_date,feed_attribute_name)
```

Be patient,it will take a while.

Comment: Can you write the syntax for such query. A pointer to some source would also do fine. I could not find anyhting suitable in a quick google search.

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
SELECT SUM(full_update_count) as total
FROM x.attribute_usage_information
WHERE marketplace_id=6  AND ptd='Y' AND processed_date>2013-12-31 AND 
      feed_attribute_name='abc';
```

The "using where" is saying that MySQL is doing a full table scan.  This is a simple query, so the only optimization approach is to create an index that reduces the number of rows being processed.  he best index for this query is `x.attribute_usage_information(marketplace_id, ptd, feed_attribute_name, processed_date, full_update_count)`.

You can create it as:

```
create index attribute_usage_information_idx on x.attribute_usage_information(marketplace_id, ptd, feed_attribute_name, processed_date, full_update_count);
```

By including `full_update_count`, this is a covering index.  That further speeds the query because all columns used in the query are in the index.  The execution engine does not need to look up values on the original data pages.

Comment: I cannot modify the database at all. I this needs administrative privilages